# Hadoop: Map output key doesn't implement WritableComparable. implementing RawComparator

Tags: java, hadoop

I would appreciate if one can help me.
I am writing a program on Hadoop. the Map output key is the class `org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.Kluster` which doesn't implement `WritableComparable`. therefore, I added

```
job.getConfiguration().setClass("mapred.output.key.comparator.class", KlusterComparable.class, RawComparator.class);
```

to my code. and defined `KlusterComparable.class` as follows:

```
    public static class KlusterComparable implements RawComparator<Kluster>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Kluster k1, Kluster k2) {
        Vector v1 = k1.getCenter();
        Vector v2 = k2.getCenter();
        int res = 0;
        int vsize;
        if(v1.size() < v2.size())
            vsize = v2.size();
        else 
            vsize = v1.size();

        for(int i=0; i<vsize; i++){
            if(v1.get(i) < v2.get(i)){
                res = -1;
                break;
            }else if(v1.get(i) > v2.get(i)){
                res = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(byte[] k1, int s1, int l1, byte[] k2,
            int s2, int l2) {
        Kluster kl1 = null;
        Kluster kl2 = null;

        byte[] b1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(k1, s1, s1+l1-1);
        byte[] b2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(k1, s2, s2+l2-1);
        try{
        kl1 = (Kluster)(SerializationUtils.deserialize(b1));
        kl2 = (Kluster)(SerializationUtils.deserialize(b2));

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception!!!");
        }
        return compare(kl1, kl2);
    }
}
```

But I got an error when I run the jar on Hadoop: `FAILED
java.io.IOException: Spill failed`

When I catch the exception I have the code print `Exception!!!`.

Comment: can u insert a default constructor in KlusterComparable.class and see whether that solves your problem.

Comment: No it's not working. the same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of `Arrays.copyOfRange` is exclusive. For example, the original array is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, `Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, 3)` will get `[1, 2]`.

Your code should be:

```
byte[] b1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(k1, s1, s1+l1);
byte[] b2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(k1, s2, s2+l2);
```

Actually, you can learn how to compare in Hadoop from [WritableComparator](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u6/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparator.java#WritableComparator). Here is an examle that borrows some ideas from it.

```
public class KlusterComparator implements RawComparator<Kluster> {

private final Kluster key1;
private final Kluster key2;
private final DataInputBuffer buffer;

public KlusterComparator() {
    key1 = new Kluster();
    key2 = new Kluster();
    buffer = new DataInputBuffer();
}

@Override
public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
    try {
        buffer.reset(b1, s1, l1); // parse key1
        key1.readFields(buffer);

        buffer.reset(b2, s2, l2); // parse key2
        key2.readFields(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return compare(key1, key2); // compare them
}

@Override
public int compare(Kluster o1, Kluster o2) {
    // compare o1 and o2
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: You should add a buffer.reset(null, 0, 0); at the end of the try block to avoid excess heap usage (issue no. HADOOP-11323)